# Exportar a txt un dataframe que fue agrupado

Tags: python, pandas

buen día

Estoy agrupando un csv que contiene solo dos campos, uno de texto y uno numérico, lo que hice es agrupar para posteriomente exportar a un archivo txt, ya que es un archivo con miles de registro. El problema está en que al exportar solamente me lleva el campo de la suma, mas no el de agrupamiento. Algún consejo que me pueda ayudar, también intente con pivot_table pero es exactamente lo mismo. Gracias

Agrego lineas. Este archivo solo contiene columnas *Clave* y *monto*.

```bash
df = pd.read_csv('Ventas.csv')  
datos=(df.groupby('Clave').agg('sum').reset_index()
datos.to_csv(nombre_archivo, sep=",", index=False)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tienes un paréntesis no cerrado en `datos=(...`, supongo que sera un error tipográfico al crear la pregunta. Independientemente de esto, no veo como reproducir tu problema si ese es todo tu código y el csv es algo como  `Clave,Monto\n aaa,600.68\n bbb,377.74\n`. Lo que comentas se explicaría si no usaras `.reset_index()` con `index=False` por ejemplo, pero no debería pasar con tu código. De hecho no necesitarias resetear el indice,  `df.groupby('Clave').agg('sum').to_csv(nombre_archivo, sep=",")` es lo mismo en cuanto al csv final.